# Issue redirecting to new page

Tags: javascript

**MY END GOAL:**
Is for a user to select a workout card which will then redirect the user to a workout page with a timer and mp4 format videos of the current exercise (for the user to do), and an upcoming exercise (which will become current exercise once timer is complete).

The timer and the videos are loaded in from firebase

**What I want to achieve:**
After redirecting to my new page I want to export the selected car's heading so that I can then use that heading to add to the firebase reference so when it loads it knows what workout videos and timer to fetch.

I hope Breaking it down has made it a little easier to understand
PS. Ignore the setTimeout. I will change that to a promise once exercise card loads in.

**CURRENT ISSUE**

I'm trying to redirect to a new page (workout page) when I click a card.

However, I receive errors on certain elements in my `userSelection.js` module after redirecting to the `workout.js` new page. I shouldn't be receiving those errors as I'm not trying to import any of that across?

I hope this makes sense.

**ERRORS APPEARING**

[image: ERROR]

workout.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js";
import letitGo from "./UserSelection.js";
import {
  getDatabase,
  ref,
  onValue,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: "danifitness.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "danifitness",
  storageBucket: "danifitness.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "194472376905",
  appId: "1:194472376905:web:82111669300a777e7b5d98",
  measurementId: "G-KCRJXR6YH8",
};

window.onload = letsGo;

function letsGo() {
  console.log("hey man");
  letitGo();
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
// Get reference
let newref = ref(database, "workout/"); // Needs to have the selected exercise heading in the url path. E.G. + I AM LEGEND

onValue(
  newref,
  (snapshot) => {
    let dataVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log(dataVal);
  },
  (errorObject) => {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.name);
  }
);

const playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn");
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pauseBtn");

playBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  startTimer();
});

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("paused!");
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
});

// Countdown Timer Animation
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green",
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD,
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD,
  },
};

const TIME_LIMIT = 20; // This will be replaced by working time
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML =
      formatTime(timeLeft);
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      //   rnds -1
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

userSelection.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js";
import {
  getDatabase,
  ref,
  onValue,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: APIKEY,
  authDomain: "danifitness.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "danifitness",
  storageBucket: "danifitness.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "194472376905",
  appId: "1:194472376905:web:82111669300a777e7b5d98",
  measurementId: "G-KCRJXR6YH8",
};

const userSelections = document.querySelector(".user-exercises");

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
// Get reference
let newref = ref(database, "workout/");

onValue(
  newref,
  (snapshot) => {
    let dataVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log(dataVal);

    const newKey = Object.keys(dataVal);
    getCards(newKey);

    const userSelHeading = document.querySelectorAll(".workoutSelHeading");
    userSelHeading.forEach((userEl) => {
      words.push(userEl.innerHTML);
      console.log(userEl);
    });
  },
  (errorObject) => {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.name);
  }
);

function timeit() {
  //   LOAD AFTER EXERCISE CARD HAS BEEN LOADED
  setTimeout(() => {
    const selectIt = document.querySelectorAll(".exercise-card");
    selectIt.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element);
      element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(element);
        letitGo();
      });
    });
  }, 3000);
}

timeit();

// USE SEARCH BAR TO SEARCH FOR WORKOUTS-------------------------------------
const searchbtn = document.querySelector(".searchBtn");
const userSearch = document.querySelector(".userSearch");

let words = [];

userSearch.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  let newLetter = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const filteredWords = words.filter((word) => {
    return word.toLowerCase().includes(newLetter);
  });
  getCards(filteredWords);
});

const getCards = (cards) => {
  const htmlString = cards.map((card) => {
    console.log(card[0]);
    return `
    <div class="exercise-card">
        <div class="exercise-img">
            <img src="" alt="Image will go here">
        </div>
        <div class="exercise-info">
            <div class="topsection">
                <!-- Pull the heading and description data -->
                <h3 class="workoutSelHeading">${card}</h3>
                <!-- What is the exercise -->
                <h5>Legs</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="des-container">
                <p>Legless is a high intensity, full lower body, resistance based leg workout bound to have you crawling out of the gym. It is a great workout if you're looking to build strength and muscle growth.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>`;
  });
  userSelections.innerHTML = htmlString.join("");
};

export default function letitGo() {
  console.log("please work");
  window.location.href = "workout"; // WORKOUT SCREEN - Redirects to the new screen to start workout
}
```

Comment: Once you redirect, none of the code from the original page keeps running. So if you want to do something after redirecting, it has to be in the destination page's JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the response, Barmar. But, that's why I'm confused, because the errors i'm receiving on my workout.js (redirected page) are coming from userSelection.js

Comment: You have `import letitGo from "./UserSelection.js";` so it's trying to reload `UserSelection.js`.

Comment: Does `.userSearch` exist on the new page after redirecting? You're getting an error from `userSearch.addEventListener`.

Comment: shouldn't importing letitgo only run whats in that function, which should only import the "please work" console log

Comment: And no {userSearch} doesn't exist in the page it's being redirected. But I thought it shouldn't be picking that up as i'm, not importing that.

Comment: That's not how import works. It runs the entire script being imported, but only assigns `letitGo` to a variable in the current script's namespace.

Comment: ok, I see. Is there to import just variable to another module instead of the whole script?

Comment: No, there isn't. It's not possible to run just part of a script. How is it supposed to know which parts have results that are needed in the variables being imported.